# Shinyapp in R code runs differently when deployed as a website versus when it is run locally

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app that works well when I run it locally from R. However, the code doesn't run the same after I've deployed it as a website.

1. The published website does not ignore repeat key presses like it does when I run the shiny app locally.
2. Moreover, it saves all previous sessions. If I open the website to start the timer then close the website it saves the previous session. I would like the datatableOutput to reset. ***erikor solved this for me***

Below is how I would like the app to run, and also how it runs when I run it locally in Rstudio:

```html
[<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tPMPHaN.gif" title="Click to enlarge.">]
```

Below is how the app runs after I have deployed it with shinyapp.io

```html
[<img src="https://i.imgur.com/UjmHbsm.gif" title="Click to enlarge.">]
```

```
                                  ------Background------
```

The shiny app is a timer for experiments my lab conducts. It starts a count up timer for the duration that a key is pressed. After the first key press it starts the "Time Lapse Since first Pre-Test Trial: " stopwatch which is just a way to keep track of the time that has lapsed since the experiment first started.

When the key is pressed it resets the "Time Lapsed: " stopwatch to keep track of the duration of time each experimental trial lasts. When the key is released it saves the time that the key was held for in `DT::dataTableOutput("TailFlickTrials")` and it also resets the "Time Lapsed: " stopwatch, so we can keep track of the time that has lapsed between each experimental trial.

Then at the end of the experiment we can click on the "Download the data" button to save the data as a .csv file locally.

I want to make this app a website so everyone in my lab who are not comfortable using R can also use this.

However, when I publish this app as a website it doesn't function the same way. It registers repeat key presses. So as I hold a key it resets the timer every millisecond. I solved this issue locally with `if (!e.repeat)`. That function in context in the code is:

```
tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("start", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                  }
                                 )
```

Moreover, it saves sessions that were previous run after I close the tab and re-open the website. I would like `DT::dataTableOutput("TailFlickTrials")` to reset for ever new session.

Necessary libraries:

```
# install.packages("shinythemes")
# install.packages("shiny")
# install.packages("DT")
# install.packages("lubridate")
# install.packages("keys")
# install.packages("vtable")
# install.packages('rsconnect')
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(keys)
library(vtable)
```

The code, I'm sorry it is so long I do not believe I can make a reproducible issue with less code:

```
my_options <- options(digits.secs = 3) # setting the digits for the timer to round up to

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = NULL,
  lang = NULL,
  hr(),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("t_exp_timer", e.key == 13, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                  }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("start", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                  }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("lapsing_timer", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                  }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("reset", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                 }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("stop", e.key == 83, {priority: "event"});
     b                            }
                                 );
                                  ')),
    titlePanel("Tail Flick Latency StopWatch"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textOutput('stopwatch')
      ),
  sidebarPanel(
    textOutput('exp_stopwatch')
  ),
  
  tags$hr(),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("TailFlickTrials")
      ),
  downloadButton('download',"Download the data")
    )


#create data frame with 0 rows and 5 columns. this is an empty data frame that will fill with values as they are generate by user
v <- reactiveValues()
v$df <- data.frame(Start_Time = numeric(), 
                   End_Time = numeric(), 
                   TimeLapsed = numeric(), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  exp_timer <- reactiveVal(0)
  exp_timer_active <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  timer <- reactiveVal(0)
  active <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  tmp_Start_Time <- numeric(0)
  tmp_End_Time <- numeric(0)

  observe({
    invalidateLater(100, session)
    isolate({
      if(active())
      {
        timer(round(timer()+0.1,3))
      }
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    invalidateLater(100, session)
    isolate({
      if(exp_timer_active())
      {
        exp_timer(round(exp_timer()+0.1,2))
      }
    })
  })
  
  # observeEvent for the keydown event
  observeEvent(input$start,{
    timer(0)
    start_timing <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    will_it_work <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    # on keydown event erase values of tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed previous saved
    tmp_End_Time <- numeric(0)
    # on keydown add one to tmp_Trial
    # on keydown, input new values for tmp_Trial, tmp_Trial_Date, and tmp_Start_Time        
    tmp_Start_Time <- Sys.time()
    # append tmp_Trial, tmp_Trial_date, tmp_Start_time to df
    # this method allows for the new row to have NA values for the End_Time and TimeLapsed columns. the code below will append those values to the row. 
    new_row <- head(v$df[NA,], 1)
    new_row[c('Start_Time')] <- list(Start_Time = tmp_Start_Time)
    v$df <- rbind(v$df, new_row)
  })
  
  # observeEvent for the keyup event
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    timer(0)
    start_timing <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    will_it_work <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    # on keyup event erase values of tmp_Trial_Date, and tmp_Start_Time, previously saved
    tmp_Start_Time <- numeric(0)
    new_row <- head(v$df[NA,], 1)
    # on keyup, input new values for tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed
    tmp_End_Time <- Sys.time()
    tmp_TimeLapsed <- round(as.numeric(difftime(tmp_End_Time, v$df[nrow(v$df), 1], units ="secs")),3)
    # on keyup, combine tmp_End_Time and tmp_TimeLapsed into new vector called tmp
    # append tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed to df's last row by called nrow() in the row and the last two columns. 
    v$df[nrow(v$df), 2] <- tmp_End_Time
    v$df[nrow(v$df), 3] <- tmp_TimeLapsed
  })

  observeEvent(input$lapsing_timer, {active(TRUE)})

  output$stopwatch <- renderText({
    paste("Time Lapsed: ", seconds_to_period(timer()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$t_exp_timer, exp_timer_active(TRUE))

  output$exp_stopwatch <- renderText({
    paste("Time Lapse Since first Pre-Test Trial: ", seconds_to_period(exp_timer()))
  })
  
  output$TailFlickTrials <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    v$df
    })
  output$download <-       
    downloadHandler(
      filename = function () {
        paste("MyData.csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(v$df, file)
      }
    )
  }

# Run the application 
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
options(rsconnect.max.bundle.files = 500000000)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like the deployed website to run the same as the shiny app does when I run it locally. I hope my code and what my problem is are both clear.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information. Thanks!

Comment: The reason your previous runs are persisting is your `v` variable is global and so will be shared across sessions. Put `v <- reactiveValues()` and the line that follows it inside your `server` function and then each session will get its own dataframe to store things in.

Comment: Oh wonderful, that solved that issue, thank you! You wouldn't happen to know why the if (!e.repeat) isn't working in a published shiny app too would you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as when I deploy your app to shinyapps.io it seems to work as expected. You can see here: https://highflowpeds.shinyapps.io/shinytest/ (note to the world in the future: that link will soon be dead).

Comment: Yours is not working the way it is supposed to. When you press and hold the spacebar it is only supposed to create one row in the data frame. When you release the space bar it will tell you how long the space bar was held down. The way your shiny app works for me in my browser is that it reads each "repeat" key. So every millisecond it will start a new run and a new "trial", without finishing the trial. I've edited my question to include gifs (low quality gifs). If you can, watch those to see what I mean.

Comment: Here is mine too. Maybe your browser reads repeat keys differently than mine?https://jacobcwhite.shinyapps.io/whyohwhy/?_ga=2.11442868.1238119290.1673381418-45672715.1673211756

Comment: Interesting. Mine and yours both work "as expected" for me. What OS and Browser are you using? Is it possible you have some security setting blocking javascript on external or unrecognized websites? Have you tried on another computer?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I just tried on a second computer and it is still not ignoring repeat keys (i.e creating a new trial/row in the datatable every millisecond instead of timing how long the space bar is held). It's possible both of my computers have blocked javascript for some reason but I never set that manually.

Comment: I do not have anything that blocks javascript. For both of the computers I have Windows 11 and Windows 10, I've used both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge to open the  links.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your previous runs are persisting is your v variable is global and so will be shared across sessions. Put v <- reactiveValues() and the line that follows it inside your server function and then each session will get its own dataframe to store things in. So instead of:

```
v <- reactiveValues()
v$df <- data.frame(Start_Time = numeric(), 
                   End_Time = numeric(), 
                   TimeLapsed = numeric(), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 ...
}
```

it should be

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues()
  v$df <- data.frame(Start_Time = numeric(), 
                     End_Time = numeric(), 
                     TimeLapsed = numeric(), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  ...
}
```

(Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the `e.repeat` issue, as this works as expected when I deploy to shinyapps.io.)